Automatic Time Zone gets disabled automatically
Automatic Time Zone gets automatically disabled once i close the settings interface or click on go back.
I keep selecting the time zone manually when i travel from one place to another.
I am on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
Any idea why the option is getting disabled automatically ?
Please let me know how to enable this option permanently.
Thanks.

Did you force the upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04.1?

No. That was clean install of 24.04 LTS on my laptop.

Then it is 24.04 not 24.04.1 that is not out yet.

I have the same problem. Haven't made sense of it yet. Possibly related to the shutdown of Mozilla Location Services; I think geolocation is basically broken for the whole OS currently. Also possibly related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-initial-setup/+bug/2068000 / https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-initial-setup/-/merge_requests/236.
